# Sending JSON object from activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Heyo guys

I've been searching for an answer for this for hours now. Could you please help. It's really important.
So what I am trying to do is to get a JSON object in an Asynctask in the Login activity and then sending this object to a Fragment where I will parse it.

Here's the Login activity's Asynctask where I try to send the JSON (which i get as a retrun from postrequest() ) :

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String JSON = null;
        try
        {

        JSON = new String(postrequest());

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("jString", JSON);
        Timetable fragobj = new Timetable();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And here's my Fragment (Timetable.class) where I try to get the JSON in onCreatView

```
String jsonString = getArguments().getString("jString");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

My problem with all that is that I always get a NullPointerException when I try to get the jsonString with getArguments.
Any help would be appreciated.
 Cheers

P.S. I hope my post isn't too chaotic XD

Comment: Do you add your Fragment before or after the AsyncTask finishes? My guess is that you are adding the Fragment before it finishes, and thus `onCreateView()` is called before `doInBackground()` completes.

Comment: Does postrequest run on a separate thread than doInBackground? In that case you maybe creating the fragment before the data is available

Comment: The crash Log says it's a NullPointer at `String jsonString = getArguments().getString("jString");`

Comment: When the async is finished the app switches to another Activity where the Fragments are created `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            Intent switcher = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            Login.this.startActivity(switcher);

        }`

Comment: You should be creating the fragment in onPostExecute

Comment: No postrequest is on the same thread as the async

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the variables from AsyncTask to Fragment use an interface and then pass it back...

In your AsyncTask do the following:

```
 public interface WebServiceResult {
     void OnWebService(int type, String result);
 }
```

That is how I have it set up so I can use the same web service for multiple different calls.

In your AsyncTask, create a constructor and have it state the interface:

```
WebServiceResult listener;
public WebService(Context c, WebServiceResult listener, JSONObject jObject,
        int typeofCall) {
    this.c = c;
    this.typeofCall = typeofCall;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.jObject = jObject;
}
```

Code from my own App.

Then after the call is complete pass by your json from the doInBackground to Your onPostExecute

```
if (result != null) {
    if (listener != null)
        listener.OnWebService(typeofCall, result);
} else {
    //Do Else Statement
}
```

This passes the variable back to your activity which you can send to the fragment using the getArguments.